# Internet Explorer display: table issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-tables, display

I'm currently working myself into display: table to improve a website I'm working on. Problem is, that it should also work on IE. But instead of setting multiple cells into one row, IE aligns my cells as one straight column.
I also tried to set a (pink) background-color during debugging but IE doesn't even show the bg-color.

Any help?

```
  .Table
  {
    display: table;
    background: #ff69b4;

  }
  .Title
  {
    display: table-header-group;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .Row
  {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .Cell
  {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    min-height: 80px;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
```

This works perfectly fine in any other browser.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the bug with randomly deleting css properties.
Got nothing todo with the display: table property, but with this:

```
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

Comment: Well, IE doesn't support CSS variables, so `var(--primary-color)` won't work.

Comment: Yeah, found that online too. It's quite a bummer, since web-design gets alot harder like that >.>

Comment: Agreed. CSS desperately needed variables right from the start. The fact that it was only implemented relatively late is unfortunate. But we are where we are. But if IE11 support is your limit, you're very lucky. Just be glad you never had to support IE6 or quirks mode, or any of that awefulness.